# Calling Stored Procedure using EF Core 7

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

Using the recently released EF Core 7, I have seen in Code magazine that you can map to stored procedures as follows (for example):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .InsertUsingStoredProcedure("PeopleInsert",
        spbuilder => spbuilder
            .HasParameter(p => p.FirstName)
            .HasParameter(p => p.LastName)
)
```

But what is the C# syntax for **calling** the stored procedure once it is mapped in this way?

I can of course call the stored procedure using FromSqlRaw as previously but I thought that the mapping would lead to a more elegant way of calling it, which I have as yet been unable to establish.

Comment: It is used during SaveChanges - EF Core Power Tools can map other stored procedures for you

Answer (score 2):

Your stored procedure will be called when you INSERT a new item (triggered by the database context). Similar setups are available for DELETE and UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks Erik and Paul. Makes sense.